# LazyLoading of children nodes in SmartGWT/extGWT

Tags: lazy-loading, smartgwt, gxt

My case is the following:
a. I've got some GWT library: extGWT or SmartGWT, for instance;
b. I've got a tree with lazy loading;
c. On expansion I load node children;
d. I've got millions of children nodes so I don't want them to load **at one go** on node expansion.

I would like to know if it's possible to use lazy loading not only on node expansion but also on tree scroll, for instance. 
I'm considering the use of extGWT / smartGWT for my project (never worked with them actually), so don't know if my question is kind of obvious. But I wasn't able to find the answer myself yet. 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a topic http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=16946 on the smartclient forum about pagination of smartGWT treegrids that isn't old.  As I understand, pagination is not implemented for treegrids as "it's just not a very good UI".
I'm not an expert in smartGWT treegrids but I think you can use "lazy loading" on node expansion with the datasource, but not on tree scroll.

As for extGWT, I really don't know.  Hope it can help you a little bit.